# PHP email template not sent

Tags: php, html, email

I have create a program for sending email with customize html format with some user date and some pre written text.

The email will not be sent and I don't know why. Here is the code:

```
$to = $_SESSION['email'];
                            $subject = 'Possword recovery';
                            $message = '<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:800px; background-color:#EEE; border:solid 1px #DDD; padding:10px;" align="center">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="padding:10px; vertical-align:middle; height:150px; background-color:#00247D; width:60%;">
                                                        <img src="http://www.welovegreatbritain.com/email/images/logo.png">
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="vertical-align:middle; background-color:#900; width:40%; color:#FFF; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                                                        <span style="font-size:12px; margin-left:30px; display:block; text-decoration:underline;">Contact Us </span>
                                                        <span style="font-size:10px; margin-left:30px; display:block; margin-top:4px;">0844-414-8582</span>
                                                        <span style="font-size:10px; margin-left:30px; display:block; margin-top:1px;">0871-288-5127</span>
                                                        <p style="margin-left:30px; margin-right:15px;">
                                                            <b style="font-size:12px;">NOTE : </b>
                                                            <span style="font-size:10px;"> If you are calling from outside UK please dial 0044 0844 414 8582 or 0044 0844 288 5127</span>
                                                        </p>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="2" style="background-color:#FFF; height:600px; padding:10px; vertical-align:top; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                                                        <h2 style="font-weight:normal; font-size:17px; color:#00247D; margin-top:25px; margin-left:25px;">Password Recovery</h2>
                                                        <p style="margin-left:25px; font-size:16px;">
                                                            Hi, we just notice that you have attampted a password recovery from the below location.
                                                            <span style="display:block; font-size:12px; margin-top:10px;">Country : <span style="margin-left:25px;">'.$country.'</span></span>
                                                            <span style="display:block; font-size:12px;">City : <span style="margin-left:47px;">'.$client_city.'</span></span>
                                                            <span style="display:block; font-size:12px;">Browser : <span style="margin-left:21px;">'.$browser.'</span></span>
                                                            <span style="display:block; font-size:12px;">OS : <span style="margin-left:50px;">'.$os.'?></span></span>
                                                            <span style="display:block; font-size:12px;">IP : <span style="margin-left:55px;">'.$client_ip.'</span></span>
                                                        </p>
                                                        <p style="margin-left:25px; margin-top:50px;">
                                                            <span style="font-size:25px;">
                                                                Cancer Research UK
                                                            </span>
                                                        </p>
                                                        <p style="margin-left:25px;">
                                                            Join our 10 minute surevy and save a life. <a href="#">Click Here</a> to join now.
                                                            <span style="display:block;">
                                                                Nothing is complecate on this surevy. You just have to answer 10 simple qustions and can save a life. 
                                                            </span> 
                                                        </p>
                                                        <p style="margin-left:25px; margin-top:60px;">
                                                            Thanks
                                                            <span style="display:block">James Cosgrove</span>
                                                        </p>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>                
                                            </tbody>
                                            <tfoot>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="vertical-align:top; padding:5px 0 0 0; color:#666; font-size:12px; border-top:solid 1px #DDD;">
                                                        <span>Maximum SRJ | </span> &copy; 2014
                                                        <span style="display:block; font-size:12px;">
                                                            Director : James Cosgrove
                                                        </span>
                                                        <span style="display:block; font-size:12px;">
                                                            Email : cosgrove@welovegreatbritain.com
                                                        </span>
                                                        <span style="display:block;font-size:12px;">
                                                            Address : BT Street, London, 401523, UK
                                                        </span>
                                                        <span>
                                                            <a href="#">Terms & Condition</a>
                                                        </span>
                                                        <span style="color:#000; font-weight:bold">|</span>
                                                        <span>
                                                            <a href="#">Privacy</a>
                                                        </span>
                                                        <span style="color:#000; font-weight:bold">|</span>
                                                        <span>
                                                            All Rights Reserved
                                                        </span>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="padding:0 0 0 0; vertical-align:top; text-align:right;  border-top:solid 1px #DDD;">
                                                        <img src="http://www.welovegreatbritain.com/email/images/flogo.png" style="margin-top:5px;" />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tfoot>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            ';

                            $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
                            $headers .= 'From: Welove Great Britain <no-reply@welovegreatbritain.com>' . "\r\n";    
                            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Also it is not showing any kind of error messages. The other function related to this page like store some user date into mysql table is work fine, too.

So, anyone please help me out with these trouble. I will be really thankful to you.

Comment: first try to check some part working or not .. then debug step by step.

Comment: `session_start();` loaded? Your email `to` is based on sessions.

Comment: where is session_start();   ? it should be at the first line.

Comment: Is your php ini setup with a smtp server and port ?

Comment: use try catch block to check the error.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL);  
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to enable  extension in php.ini. Maby SMTP is outlined with ";" sign.

Comment: Hin @Tyga21, I think your solution will work. But how to edit php.ini on my hosting?